# Storing/Saving XML in local asset folder in AIR

Tags: air, flash-builder

AIR in general seems to be storing the xml file in the path where the app is installed. 
I am generating an xml and I want to save/store a xml file in local asset folder of AIR application.

Any thoughts on doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File class has some static variables that point to local directories:

From the docs:

> - File.applicationStorageDirectory — a storage directory unique to each installed AIR application
> - File.applicationDirectory — the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)
> - File.desktopDirectory — the user's desktop directory
> - File.documentsDirectory — the user's documents directory
> - File.userDirectory — the user directory

**Creating a pointer to the file**

Usually you'll want to store files like these in File.applicationStorageDirectory.
So to create the file do:

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("my-config.xml");
```

Alternatively, you can let the user choose where to store the file by using [File#browseForSave()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForSave%28%29), which will display a native 'save' window to choose the location.

**Writing the content**

Open a FileStream for the File in 'write' mode and write an XML string to the file.

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTF(myXmlContent);
fs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html

http://www.thetechlabs.com/xml/how-to-build-a-contact-manager-in-air-using-xml-part-2/

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

```
var prefsFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
prefsFile = prefsFile.resolvePath("preferences.xml");
stream = new FileStream();
stream.open(prefsFile, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes(outputStringXML);
```

Or something like:

```
var saveStr:String = xmlToSave.toXMLString();
var file:File = new File('app-storage:/data.xml');
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);    
fs.writeUTFBytes(saveStr);
fs.close();
```