# Loading saved contents back in their places in flex air using flash builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have now gotten the idea of saving multiple components text into one file. But now when I open that file all the text in the file goes into the text of only one component. Here is the code,

```
                        <s:click>

                            var f:File = File.desktopDirectory;

                            f.browseForSave("Save As");

                            f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function (event:Event):void {

                            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();

                            stream.open((event.target as File),FileMode.WRITE);

                            stream.writeUTFBytes(rte.htmlText);

                            stream.writeUTFBytes(ta.text);

                            stream.writeUTFBytes(rich.text);

                            stream.close();

                            });

                        </s:click>

                    </s:Button>
```

```
                        <s:click>

                            var f:File = File.desktopDirectory;

                            f.browseForOpen("Select file to open", []);

                            f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function (event:Event):void {

                            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();

                            fs.open(event.target as File, FileMode.READ);

                            rte.htmlText = fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable);

                            ta.text = fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable);

                            fs.close();

                            });

                        </s:click>

                    </s:Button>
```

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You already read all the stream from the fs.
As soon as you execute once fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable); the read header/pointer will be indicating to your end of your file, so in the next line the bytesAvailable will be zero.

I suggest you use the following code:

```
<s:click>
    var f:File = File.desktopDirectory;
    f.browseForOpen("Select file to open", []);

    f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function (event:Event):void {
        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fs.open(event.target as File, FileMode.READ);

        var dataStr:String = fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable);

        rte.htmlText = dataStr;
        ta.text      = dataStr;

        // if you want only the non formatted text use:   ta.text = rte.text;
        fs.close();
});
</s:click>
```

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thanks for the answer, however when I run with your code it fills the rich textbox with all the data typed by the user, that is the data typed in the rich texteditor, the textarea and the richeditable text area and places the code in the ta.text textarea. The Idea is that the client types data into those three fields which are each sitting on a different tab in a tabnavigator. On pressing the save button all three components' text must save into one file. On opening the file again all three components must be filled with the data the user typed in before saving. Hope you can help

Comment: Hi @MariusNel, I am not completely sure what you want to achieve with that, and why you save 3 different texts in same file ? Maybe try explain better to have a better solution for your issue

Comment: Hi Adrian, the full scale of my problem is at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227453/adobe-air-with-flex-file-new-open-and-save-for-desktop-software-program. That will explain exactly what it is that I am trying to achieve. I still have not gotten that right. Thanks so much for your input Adrian it is really appreciated.